# How do you determine what type of CPU socket a linux computer has?

Tags: linux, central-processing-unit, socket

What Linux command/program can I use to tell me what type of CPU socket a Linux desktop has?

I use CPUZ or SIW on windows, and I can use "cat /proc/cpuinfo" on Linux to get the rest of the possessor's information, But it does not tell me which socket the CPU is.

Thanks.

Comment: I like to use a program called screwdriver.  :p

Comment: looking at the board is much faster
also check the spec on the machine/board maker

most linux will tell you is chipsets, processor archs, and speeds tmk.

Comment: ...and is ultimately the only reliable means.

Comment: Zoredache, I like your style.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have [x86info](http://www.codemonkey.org.uk/projects/x86info/) installed you can run it with `x86info -a` and you will get something like this:

```
x86info v1.11.  Dave Jones 2001, 2002
Feedback to <davej@suse.de>.

Need to be root to use specified options.
Found 1 CPU
eax in: 0x00000000, eax = 00000002 ebx = 756e6547 ecx = 6c65746e edx = 49656e69
eax in: 0x00000001, eax = 00000686 ebx = 00000002 ecx = 00000000 edx = 0383f9ff
eax in: 0x00000002, eax = 03020101 ebx = 00000000 ecx = 00000000 edx = 0c040882

Family: 6 Model: 8 Stepping: 6 Type: 0
CPU Model: Pentium III (Coppermine) [cC0] Original OEM
Feature flags:
 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 mmx fxsr sse

Instruction TLB: 4KB pages, 4-way associative, 32 entries
Instruction TLB: 4MB pages, fully associative, 2 entries
Data TLB: 4KB pages, 4-way associative, 64 entries
L2 unified cache:
    Size: 256KB 8-way associative.
    line size=32 bytes.
L1 Instruction cache:
    Size: 16KB  4-way associative.
    line size=32 bytes.
Data TLB: 4MB pages, 4-way associative, 8 entries
L1 Data cache:
    Size: 16KB  4-way associative.
    line size=32 bytes.

Connector type: Socket 370 (FC-PGA) or (PPGA)


930.33 MHz processor (estimate).
```

Answer (score 15):

This works for me: `dmidecode -t processor`.

Other types are: `bios`, `system`, `baseboard`, `chassis`, `memory`, `cache`, `connector`, `slot`.

Comment: It seems "dmidecode -t 4" is more usefull then the "x86info" as it seems "x86info" only knows about older hardware, while dmidecode gives a "Socket Designation" on newer hardware as well.

Answer (score 3):

What model is the processor? CPU-Z and cat /proc/cpuinfo should say. Once you find the processor type , Google will find you specifications on said processor which does have the socket type.

Comment: seems a perfectly valid solution.